# How to reshape a column vector into a matrix block by block in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm trying reshape a column vector into a matrix block by block. I'm aware of the mat2cell fucntion in MATLAB, but I'm unsure how to apply this to my problem.

For example If I have a 12x1 Vector:

A =

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
```

And I wanted to split this into 3 blocks, each a 4x1 Vector, and then stack them next to each other as below:

B =

```
 1     5     9
 2     6    10
 3     7    11
 4     8    12
```

How would I use the mat2cell function to do this?

Thanks

Comment: why use `mat2cell`? Couldn't you use `B = reshape(A,4,[])`?

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Yup... I also managed to (finally) find a duplicate.  Can you believe that it took me 10 minutes to find a suitable duplicate? I'm sure this question has been asked many times.

Comment: @rayryeng maybe you should upvote it then? No votes duplicates are hard to find.

Comment: @patrik you aren't able to use duplicates that have no votes. The post I linked already has upvotes. Besides which, I already did.